# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'long' and 'str'

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python, typeerror

With this code:

```
current_time=time.localtime()
time_now=time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',current_time)

cursor.execute("Select * from SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILS where Alert_time='%s'") % time_now
```

I get the error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for %:long and str
```

`type` of `Alert_time` is varchar

Comment: Hi there, and welcome. Sometimes it takes a while before someone has time to answer your question, maybe a few hours, maybe even days. Be patient! Asking again after 5 minutes is typically not considered very friendly :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misplaced your `%`

What you're doing now is:

```
cursor.execute("[snip]") % time_now
```

So you're applying `time_now` on the result of `cursor.execute`

What you want is use the `%` with the string, like so:

```
cursor.execute("[snip]" % time_now)
```

**BUT don't do this, you should use:**

```
cursor.execute("Select * from SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILS where Alert_time=%s", (time_now,))
```

Note that here, we're passing `time_now` as a second parameter, instead of using the `%` operator. This will make sure the query is properly sanitized, to prevent SQL injection attacks.

The (somewhat ugly) trailing `,` is needed to make sure the second argument is a tuple.

Comment: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
I m getting this error when I change the code

Comment: time_now=time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',current_time)
    cursor.execute("Select * from SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILS where Alert_time=?",(time_now,)